# magento slider not showing

Tags: magento, slider

I'm novice in magento, i'm using 1.9 version and I have bought a theme (mozar), but when I want to put de banner7 slider or featured slider in front page not showing, I have activate both in magentothem configuration, and slide in banner7 and feature product in some products

Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check jquery or javascript loaded properly ? also clear cache in admin panel

Comment: Hi Sagar, I clear the cache in administration and deleting the session and cache folders in the xampp server, but nothig happens.

Comment: check you browser console. there must be js/jquery error.

Comment: Thank you both, the problem was that there was an alternative design defined in System-> design and was overriding the theme, now the slider is visible, but the block "featured products" and other not, they are defined in the content of the homepage ({{block type="cms/block" block_id="banner_home1"}}, {{block type="featuredproductslider/featuredproductslider" name="featuredproductslider" template="magentothem/featuredproductslider/featuredproductslider.phtml"}} ... ) "ma_mozar1_home" but nothing of what I put in the content shows.

Comment: I have found the issue, in the home page I was putting a cms block, a featured product block and the lastes product block, I quit the latest product block and the content shows perfectly. Then I try to find the problem with latest block...

Comment: great ! mark this question as done

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.smartparcelbox.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#recently').bxSlider({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    slideWidth: 80,
    slideMargin:15,
    controls: true,
    infiniteLoop:false,
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 4,
    moveSlides: 1,
    preloadImages:'all'
  });
});     
</script>
```